# SQL 2005 Replication Create/Delete Tables, Views, and Procs

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I have replication setup on a couple SQL2005 servers.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870(v=sql.105).aspx replication works when changing an item.

How do I have replication pick up new tables and proced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding tables (or articles) involves adding the article to the publication, generating a new snapshot, and synchronizing the subscription(s) to apply the schema and data for the newly added article.

See [Add Articles to and Drop Articles from Existing Publications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493.aspx)